# How to gunzip and copy files in a loop

Tags: linux, shell

I've a situation where I've to read list of gunzip files (for eg: **test.gz**, **test[2020]*.gz**) gunzip them and move it to a different folder(temp). I am using linux bash shell.
So far I've done this:

```
for f in *.gz
do
 gunzip $f
done
```

When I run the script, the file is successfully gunzipped as **test.csv**, **test[2020].csv** respectively.

After that I don't know how to copy the gunzipped files (csv file) to "temp" folder.

Should I open another loop after this code? Or can I gunzip and copy the files in a single loop?

I also want to pause for few minutes between each copy to "temp" folder.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.gz` suffix from the variable and copy the file with that name.

```
for f in *.gz
do
    gunzip "$f"
    cp "${f%.gz}" temp
    sleep 60 # sleep 1 minute
done
```

Comment: @user13906858 : Contrary to your stated use-case, you could also save space  (and time), by `gunzip -c "$f" > temp/"${f%.gz}"` Good luck.

Comment: I was going to do that in my answer, but the question says copy, not move.

Comment: yes I agree with answering the question as stated. I just wanted to give them an option they may have not thought of. Good luck to all!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is not to copy *.gz file into temp dir. Is it right?
If you use "find", that can work well.

```
for f in *.gz
do
 gunzip $f
 mv $(find . -type f -depth 1 \! -name "*.gz") temp
done
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to run `mv $(find ...*.gz) temp for each `.gz` file that is found by the `for` loop. They'll all be moved after the first file in the loop is processed.